# how can i modify regex to match all urls on page

Tags: regex, url

I nave an regex for search a simple url:

https://regex101.com/r/UmMEMl/1/

It matches a simple url in the text. How can i modify this regex to match **ALL** urls in the text?

I'm not so good in regexes, so could somebody please take a look

Comment: You have emphasized on the word ALL. While the regex in the accepted answer is good, it cannot catch ALL urls, not by a long shot. You should do more research and try to qualify your question better. The question and its current answer are quite misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you didnt put flag.

- Add the 'g' flag for 'global' (meaning the regex dont stop at the first match)
- add the 'm' flag for multiline search meaning start and end anchor (^ and $) match start and end of line instead of the whole text.

https://regex101.com/r/UmMEMl/2

Edit:

your original regex was `#^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$#`

and you need

`#^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$#gm`  (notice the two letters at the end, its the flags)

Edit2

you can shorten your regex

`#^(https?:\/\/(www\.)?)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$#gm`

Note that `abc|abdc|ab|abd` can be written `abd?c?` and that's what i did shortened with your `http:\/\/|https:\/\/|...`

Answer (score 1):

Writing a regex to match **ALL** urls is not a trivial task. Take a look at [this link](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) and choose one that meets your needs. Both the one you have linked to and the one in the other answer fail on many of more complex url strings in that link.